# Fork pancakeswap frontend

Tags: cryptocurrency, binance-smart-chain, decentralized-applications

Trying to fork pancakeswap from https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-frontend.

Steps what I did,

1. Clone Repo
2. Run npm install command
3. Run npm start command
4. Solve some no-used props error by commenting that props. After that also 2 errors are still in application.

Error1: JSX props should not use functions  react/jsx-no-bind

Error2: defaultProp "expanded" has no corresponding propTypes declaration  react/default-props-match-prop-types

Help me to solve this. Stuck more than 5 days. Searched many pages but no use. Most of them are suggested to change jsx functions. Is there is any simple way to solve these errors?

[image: Before commenting unused props]

[image: After commenting unused props]

Answer (score 0):

I did the same yesterday and it worked. There are still some elements that I need to figure out, but to make it running on localhost wasn't hard.

Before running pancakeswap frontend we need to have nodejs installed. Should work with any version 16, my was v16.14.0. Second is to have installed yarn as they don't use npm. This we know because the project has yarn.lock file. Third is have nextjs installed globally like yarn. With this we should be able to install and run the app.

Next steps would be:

1. Clone repo or just download it, will work as well
2. Run yarn install command (or just yarn - works the same)
3. Run yarn build (this will call next build)
4. Run yarn start (this will call next start)

After last step the app should start on localhost:3000

This is what I did and it worked. Keep in mind that this is valid for the current version and could change in future.